# Launching Chromium from Puppeteer is timing out on a certain machine - TimeoutError: waiting for target failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Tags: google-chrome, automated-tests, puppeteer, chromium

I am getting the below error when running Puppeteer and launching Chromium. Also, Chromium opens up as crashed page. I am unable to navigate to any URL from the window that opens up.

Surprisingly, I get this error only when running from a certain machine (in my corporate network). When running from another machine in my corporate network as well as my laptop, it works fine.

Upon looking around, I noticed the recommendation to add `ignoreDefaultArgs: [ '--disable-extensions' ] }` to the config, which I did, but still receive the same error. Would you have any recommendation on what I am missing?

The error message is as follows

```
LOG >> -- START PUPPY --
(node:12008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for target failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
    at Object.waitWithTimeout (C:\Users\afhassan\Puppy\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\helper.js:224:26)
    at Browser.waitForTarget (C:\Users\afhassan\Puppy\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Browser.js:269:45)
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (C:\Users\afhassan\Puppy\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\Launcher.js:100:27)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:12008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12008) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The error is caused by this line

`this._browser = await launch(CONFIG.launchOptions);`

`launch` is imported from Puppeteer

```
import {
    Browser,
    Page,
    launch,
    CDPSession
} from 'puppeteer';
```

My config is as follows

```
{ verbose: true,
  launchOptions: { headless: false },
  defaultViewPort: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
  domain: 'domain.com',
  mySiteDomain: 'domain.com',
  users:
   { admin:
      { username: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypassword' },
     user0:
      { username: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypassword' } },
  tests: [ 'NameOfTest' ],
  ignoreDefaultArgs: [ '--disable-extensions' ] }
```

The relevant parts of my package.json is as follows

```
"dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^5.5.0",
    "yargs": "^15.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/puppeteer": "^5.4.2",
    "@types/yargs": "^15.0.11",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  }
```